# What is "operator->()" in C++?

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

I came across a C++ code that has something like operator->() being called. Below is the code snippet, should someone please explain it.

```
template <typename T>
bool List<T>::operator == (const List& rhs)const
{
  return (this == &rhs) || (root_.operator->() == rhs.root_.operator->());
}
```

Please note that root_ is object of another class of which full code is not available to me.

**EDIT: I just explored the code and found that root_ is actually a custom implementation of a smart pointer. It has operator -> overloaded in it to dereference the smart pointer and get the actually pointer's value.**

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operators_in_C_and_C%2B%2B#Member_and_pointer_operators

Answer (score 11, accepted):

When you have an object, you can access its attributes via `object.attr`. When you have a pointer, you can access the attributes of *the object it's pointing on* by using the `->` operator like so: `ptr->attr`.

So far this is the default behavior in C. However, the `->` operator can be overloaded - i.e., overridden like any function can. You can define your own behavior for a class so that `object->` will mean whatever you want. However, I don't believe that in this context, the operator was overloaded. The weird syntax is because you can't just do this:

```
if lhs-> == rhs->
```

Since the `->` operator must be followed by something. So the way to do it is to use the explicit, no-sugar, name for this function, i.e., `operator->`, and call it like a function (hence the parenthesis).

So:

```
return (this == &rhs) || (root_.operator->() == rhs.root_.operator->());
```

This line's meaning is "return true if the my object equals to the object on the left **or** if our `_root` attributes point to objects which are equal among themselves.".

Comment: How can you know it's meaning when you don't know how (probably overloaded) operator -> works? It can be overloaded to return boolean value if the object was creating during full moon. Another thing you cannot write (&obj).operator->(), it won't compile, it means that root_ is not a pointer. Non pointer object doesn't have operator-> defined at all so it only means that in this case operator-> got defined in this class.

Comment: Hey thanks buddy. Your answer lead me into looking a bit deeper into my code and found that root_ is a custom implementation of a smart pointer and operator -> is overloaded to dereference the smart pointer and get value of actual pointer.

Comment: @PiotrJaszkowski `operator&` can be overloaded as well ;)

Comment: @DyP also obj can be defined as 1234 by #define obj 1234. It will also cause this snippet to not compile.

Answer (score 4):

What you're asking about is called the *Structure dereference operator* : `T::operator ->();` It comes from [c](/questions/tagged/c), and in [c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) it can be overloaded.

It selects an element through pointer and used in the way it is used in your example it simply returns the address of the instance (`root_`).

The address is then used to compare identity of instances (do the addresses match?)

Answer (score 0):

It is the call of the overload of the `->` operator of the class.

Comment: Somehow I don’t think this answer is particularly helpful.

Comment: Somehow it answer the question in the topic in the exact terms.

Comment: So he must be a Technical Helpline Operator, gives the precise and correct answer, but is not very useful! </humour>

Comment: @Thomas So does the answer “10 minutes later than 10 minutes ago” to the question “what time is it?”. Yet neither is helpful. Here’s a joke for you: http://stackoverflow.com/a/234419/1968

Answer (score 0):

Usually operator->() returns a pointer, so this code is just comparing two pointers. I think it's a linked list implementation, and operator== compares pointers to entire list and pointers to head (root) element